# Lenovo Yoga 510 freeze problem

Tags: lenovo

I recently bought a new Lenovo Yoga 510. Getting rid of Windows 10 took me long enough but I managed to boot from USB and install Ubuntu 16.04 the usual way (by erasing Windows 10).

The thing is after around 5 to 10 minutes in Ubuntu, everything freezes except the mouse. It can move but not interact with anything (hovering over icons also doesn't make them react). I tried rebooting, doing a fresh install, seeing if something I installed caused it, but nothing. I also did tests using the Checkbox application for tests (memtest, HDD, CPU, GPU...), but they all came back with no errors. After not finding a solution at all, I figured there must be some mystery problem with the computer and I exchanged it for another one of the same model.

Surprise, the new laptop has exactly the same issues. I've been using Ubuntu for almost 10 years now and this is definitely the worst I've ever been through. Any ideas?

Comment: This is not an answer, just a thought.
THe Yoga is a 10 point touch screen device and it is possible that there is some mis match between what the hardware is expecting [tuoches on the screen] and the software. So, even when the mouse is moving, the hardware is expecting the screen to be hit. And as Ubuntu is non touch......

As I say, not an answer, but this it is this fear that has stopped me buying a 2-1 device.

Comment: Do you think turning off the touch-screen function in some way would solve the problem?

Comment: It is certainly worth a try, if it is possible. I would not know where to start.

Comment: @Piloti : It is not just a mouse problem, however. It happened often while I was doing apt update, and I'm not even using the mouse to do that. Maybe it makes the computer freeze for some reason.

Comment: @Piloti : I disabled the touchscreen and the laptop froze like 2 minutes after that. I was barely trying to install Vim!

Comment: I did a little hunting and found these:
[A]https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Linux-Discussion/Ubuntu-16-04-on-Ideapad-510/td-p/3437310
[B] https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Linux-Discussion/Re-Yoga-510-great-with-Linux-apart-from-touchscreen/td-p/3525974

It seems the main issue is actually Unity, so another desktop [Mate seems to work] might do the trick.....

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with a Lenovo 510 14AST with an AMD chipset. After a lot of testing I found out that the AMD Radeon graphics model R5 is too new to be supported by the mesa open source VGA driver.

So I did a fresh install of Xubuntu (which behaved most stable due to a simpler GUI) and then immediately installed the AMDGPU-PRO driver as described here http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/AMDGPU-PRO-Install.aspx