# How to fix black screen after login on lenovo yoga 510 Ubuntu 20.04. (possibly related to amdgpu driver.)

Tags: drivers, graphics, login, shutdown

I dual boot Ubuntu and windows. recently I found that my laptop wouldn't shut off. It would just continue like I haven't pressed shutdown button.
I thought I managed to fix the issue. but unfortunately don't remember what I did. (maybe edited some power settings? like blank screen never off or something.)
Later I noticed the laptop wasn't shutting down properly because the light on the side of the laptop was still on.
I looked into the problem and saw that it has something to do with graphics driver.
In the about page it says it uses AMD Stoney for graphics.

I went into Software & Updates and ticked some of the boxes for canonical partners and tick a box for software that is restrict by copyright in the hope that a better driver would install next update so my laptop would shut off properly.

But now after I login and I get a bright black screen. (this is a little different to the the black screen when turning off because then the screen is completely turned off when I shutdown, but the light on the side of the laptop is still on.)

It is still working fine, I just can't see anything.
I know this because I can press the windows key and type shutdown, hit arrow key twice, enter and the screen and stuff will turn off. (Of course the previous problem of not turning off fully still persists,)

I don't have any of these problems when I boot from recovery mode. It gives me a message saying not all graphics drivers will load when I boot and I login and everything is perfect. It even shuts off properly too. In the about page it says it's using llvm pipe for graphics.

Is there something I can do. can I downgrade the AMD graphics drivers? if so how do I do this?
I have looked at some answers on here. But I a lot of them are for nvidia drivers and the commands might be different for AMD.
any help would be greatly appreciated.

TLDR:
Lenovo laptop won't shutdown properly possibly because of AMDGPU graphics driver issue. I don't know what to do to stop this. I tried editing the grub file and adding acpi=force or something and some other things based on previous questions posted here. but I haven't had much luck.

Now the laptop shows a black screen after I login and I can't see the desktop. but it's still working because the screen is on and I can shut it down without seeing the screen by pressing windows key and typing shutdown and hitting enter.(it still doesn't shutdown proper)
how can I fix this issues with the graphic driver, for now I just boot in from recovery mode and everything works perfectly fine (I think it is because it uses a different driver.)

Comment: I'm going to see if I can try the solution this guy suggests soon. https://askubuntu.com/a/993326/1566087

Comment: I installed some drivers from the amd website using the link in the question in the comment I left above. It is logging into the desktop just fine now. But the problem when shutting down is still there. I am going to look at the logs to see what happens when I revisit this tomorrow. Hopefully I can fine a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue, I changed the windowing system to x11 and it worked for me. Here is a link that can give you more info https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/choose-switch-linux-display-managers/
Basically you log out, click on your profile, and click the tiny gear in the bottom right corner. It will show you a list of various display managers, I recommend selecting x11, but you can select whichever one you want.

Comment: Thank you that seems to have solved the problem. I thought I had resolved it by installing the drivers from the AMD website. but then it stopped working after a day. Your solution seems much better. I installed Lightdm and it's working great now. although there was a notification saying the screen lock only works with the gnome display manager. but that's not an issue for me. I really appreciate your response because now I can use the integrated graphics on my laptop and play games and stuff!